Locally Lipschitz with respect to a variable uniformly to another implies Lipschitz for every compact subset
I was reading a proof of Picard-Lindelöf theorem and there is a step in the proof which needs the following proposition, which I have not been able to prove.
Let $$f:A\subset{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}\to{\mathbb{R}^{n}}$$ $$(t,\mathbf{y})\to{f(t,\mathbf{y})}$$ with $A$ open, $t\in{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\mathbf{y}\in{\mathbb{R}^{n}}$.
The function $f$ is said to be locally Lipschitz in $A$ with respect to $\mathbf{y}$ uniformly in $t$, if for every $(s,\mathbf{y})\in{A}$ there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $(s,\mathbf{y})$ and a number $L\in{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $$(t,\mathbf{x}),(t,\mathbf{z})\in{U}\implies{|f(t,\mathbf{x})-(t,\mathbf{z})|\le{L|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{z}|}}$$
The function $f$ is said to be Lipschitz in $A$ with respect to $\mathbf{y}$ uniformly in $t$, if there is $L\in{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $$(t,\mathbf{x}),(t,\mathbf{z})\in{A}\implies{|f(t,\mathbf{x})-(t,\mathbf{z})|\le{L|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{z}|}}$$
Prove the following proposition:
If $f$ is locally Lipschitz in $A$ with respect to $\mathbf{y}$ uniformly in $t$, then for every compact subset $K\subset{A}$, $f$ is Lipschitz in $K$ with respect to $\mathbf{y}$ uniformly in $t$.
I know and understand the proof of this fact when we consider "normal" Lipschitz continuity - i.e. for $$f:A\subset{\mathbb{R}^n}\to{\mathbb{R}^m}$$ $$|f(x)-f(y)|\le{L|x-y|}$$ and there are also some question about that on this site. What I don't understand is how to extend the proof when we require the Lipschitz condition to hold with respect to a variabile uniformly to the other.
In my understanding, the proof of the proposition for the "normal" case relies on the fact that the local Lipschitz condition implies continuity everywhere and that the continous image of a compact set is also compact.
In this case however, the local Lipschitz condition does not imply continuity but only continuity with respect to $\mathbf{y}$ so we can not use the same line of reasoning.
Any suggestions?
Edit: I managed to prove that if $t\in{\mathbb{R}}$ is such that $$K_t=K\cap{(\{t\}\times{\mathbb{R}^n})}\neq{\emptyset}$$ then there exist $L(t)\in{\mathbb{R}}$, depending on $t$, for which the Lipschitz condition hold for all $(t,\mathbf{x}),(t,\mathbf{y})\in{K_t}$.
If I can show that $t\to{L(t)}$ is bounded then the proposition follows.
Unfortunately I can not progress from here.

Suppose (t,x) and (t,y) are in K but not in the same open set of the subcover you describe. I don't understand how to show that the Lipschitz condition hold for such points. @N.Pullbacki

You are right, apologies.

This answer implicitly assumes that $A$ is connected.
I am not a fan of sequence based proofs, but it makes quick work here, so...
For $S \subset A$, let $L_S = \sup_{(t,x),(t,z) \in S, x \neq z} {|f(t,x)-f(t,z) | \over \|x-z\|}$.
Let $K \subset A$ be compact. Suppose $L_K = \infty$, then there are $t_k,x_k,z_k$ (in $K$, as appropriate, with $x_k \neq z_k$) such that ${|f(t_k,x_k)-f(t_k,z_k) | \over \|x_k-z_k\|} \to \infty$. Since $K$ is compact, we can assume that $t_k \to t^*, x_k \to x^*, z_k \to z^*$ for some $t^*,x^*,z^*$ (in $K$, as appropriate). We must have $x^* \neq z^*$, otherwise this would contradict the local bounded assumption. However, if $\|x^*-z^*\| > 0$, then clearly ${|f(t_k,x_k)-f(t_k,z_k) | \over \|x_k-z_k\|}$ is also bounded, which is a contradiction. Hence $L_k$ is bounded.

Thanks for you answer. I don't understand the last part. If the denominator approach |x-z|>0, why the sequence is bounded? @copper.hat

The numerator is bounded and the denominator is bounded away from zero.

I don't see why the numerator is bounded. The function is not necessarly continous so I am really struggling to understand why what you say is true. For the "normal" (in the sense of the post) case, the Lipschitz condition implies continuity and thus boundness on a compact set. But here that does not hold. @copper.hat

@zinne98 The '$t$' is the same everywhere in the expression. Use the local hypothesis with $|f(t_k,x_k)-f(t_k,z_k) | = |f(t_k,x_k)-f(t_k, x^)+ f(t_k,x^)-f(t_k,z^)+f(t_k,z^)-f(t_k,z_k) |$ to see boundedness.

I think I am almost there. So from what you wrote, we apply the triangle inequality. $|f(t_k,x_k)-f(t_k,x*)|$ and $|f(t_k,z*)-f(t_k,z_k)|$ are bounded since eventually the points fall in a neighbourhood of $(t,x*)$ and $(t,z*)$ respectively for which we can use the local hypotesis. But for the middle term $|f(t_k,x*)-f(t_k,z*)|$ we can't argue in the same way since the points approach $(t,x*)$ and $(t,z*)$ which are different points. You have been very patient, can you help me finish with this last point? @copper.hat

@zinne98 I think you found a weakness in my proof. If $A$ is path connected, then you can find a polygonal path joining $x^,z^$ and apply the local approach along the path to bound the difference. However, if $A$ is not path connected then I imagine one could construct a counterexample.

Yeah this is trickier than it seems! Thanks on again for your effort.

I added another answer with a counterexample if $A$ is not connected.

Did the proof that you working with assume connectedness?

No, the proposition was the one I wrote in the post, with no particular condition on the open set A. So it is actually false as you showed. By the way I am still not sure I completely understand the proof when A is connected. My doubt is that you can not Always joint (t,y) and (t,z) by a "vertical" line so I struggle to male the inequalities work. If you don't mind could you post it here or give me some hint?

I think more that just connectedness & openness of $A$ is needed. Perhaps a simpler assumption would be that $A$ has the form $T \times X$ where $X$ is open and connected. Alternatively, some conditions on $f$ related to the the '$t$' behaviour. The purpose being to bound $f(t,x^)-f(t,z^)$ for any $x^,z^ \in X$.

Here is a counterexample if $A$ is disconnected:
Let $A_p=\mathbb{R} \times B(p,1)$, and $A = A_{-2} \cup A_2$. Define
$f(t,x) = \begin{cases} 0, & (t,x) \in A, t \le 0 \\
0, & (t,x) \in A_{-2}, t >0 \\
{1 \over t}, & (t,x) \in A_{2}, t >0 \\
\end{cases}$.
Note that $f(t,x)-f(t,z) = 0$ if ($t,x), (t,z) \in A_p$ (for $p=-2,2$).
Let $K= [0,1] \times \overline{B}(-2, {1 \over 2}) \cup [0,1] \times \overline{B}(2, {1 \over 2})  \subset A$. $K$ is clearly compact.
However, if $t \in (0,1]$, $(t,x) \in A_{-2}, (t,z) \in A_2$, then
$f(x,t)-f(z,t) = -{1 \over t}$ which is unbounded.
